# Having existing pair of crt/private key how can I generate new private key and new CSR for renewing the SSL certificate?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I need to renew SSL certificate for the first time. I do not have original CSR, but I do have `certificate.crt`/`private.key` pair. The system told me I need to specify the same data in CSR to be accepted. It would be nice to also generate new `private_new.key` in the process.

How can I generate new `csr.csr`/`private_new.key` pair using OpenSSL command line utility?

The server in question is webserver/apache2 hosted on VPS

Comment: This feels a bit light on details. You may wish [edit] your question and add what software you're using (e.g. webserver, any Let's Encrypt software, etc.) and who the certificate is being issued through.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Sorry for that, I thought CSR are specific to webservers. The certificate is issued to my own organization

Comment: @PiotrK CSRs are a certificate's request to be signed [Certificate Signing Request].

Comment: @JW0914 Yes, I know - does that affect my question somehow?

Comment: @PiotrK No, it was mentioned because of your prior comment - a CSR is required for any certificate that needs to be digitally signed, not just a webserver's _(such as certs for a signed CA, an ICA, VPN client, code signing, etc., as any cert needing to be digitally signed needs a CSR in order to be signed)_

Answer (score 2):

To generate a new key and CSR:

```bsh
openssl req -out 'apache.csr' -new -sha512 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout 'apache.key.pem' -nodes
```

1. The above assumes you have a working `openssl.cnf`, but if you do not, use [this](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSL/Linux/openssl.cnf) one and modify the V3 and SAN profiles below *(to make this simpler, leave the `sophos` name as is)*:

   ```ini
   #-----------------------------------------------------------
                    ##----- SAN Profile -----##
   #-----------------------------------------------------------

     # Lines 189 - 193

       # IP.1:  If it has a static IP, set it here, else change to 127.0.0.1
                # and delete IP.2

       # IP.2:  If it has more than one static IP, set it in IP.2, etc;
                # If the webserver can be accessed via SSH, 127.0.0.1 must
                # remain but can be in IP.3, IP.4, etc. if other IPs exist

       # DNS.1: If it has an FQDN, set it
       # DNS.2: If it has more than one FQDN, and/or a local domain name,
                # set it in DNS.2, etc., else remove DNS.2

       # If your cert requires OIDs to be specified, you'd specify each
         # in the same fashion as below, adding a line below DNS.2 for
         # either RID.1 or otherName.1 (see lines 159 - 161)

   [ alt_sophos ]
   IP.1                    = 192.168.2.1
   IP.2                    = 127.0.0.1
   DNS.1                   = your.fqdn.com
   DNS.2                   = UTM.WRT
   ```

   ```ini
   #-----------------------------------------------------------
                     ##----- V3 Profile -----##
   #-----------------------------------------------------------

     # Lines 331 - 337
       # DO NOT change anything unless you know with 100% certainty one
       # of these parameters needs to be changed

   [ v3_sophos ]
   basicConstraints        = critical, CA:FALSE
   subjectKeyIdentifier    = hash
   authorityKeyIdentifier  = keyid:always, issuer:always
   keyUsage                = critical, nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, keyAgreement
   extendedKeyUsage        = critical, serverAuth
   subjectAltName          = @alt_sophos
   ```
2. Create the required files and directories in the directory you will be working in:

   ```bsh
   # openssl can error out if these don't exist since they're in the openssl.cnf

     # Create openssl.cnf required directories:
       mkdir -p ~/ssltemp/ca ; cd ssltemp ; mkdir cert ; mkdir crl

     # Create openssl.cnf required files:
       echo 01 > crl\crlnumber ; echo 00 > serial ; echo > index ; echo > rand

     # Copy openssl.cnf from ~
       cp ~/openssl.cnf .
   ```

   *Normally the `openssl.cnf` is located at `/etc/openssl/openssl.cnf`, however depending on if you have permission to write to that directory, you can place it at `~/openssl.cnf`*
3. Create the private key and CSR:

   ```bsh
   # This should be done on the server, as the key is not encrypted:
     openssl req -out 'apache.csr' -new -sha512 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout 'apache.key.pem' -config './openssl.cnf' -extensions v3_sophos -nodes
   ```

   *Do not input the cert's HN, FQDN, or IP into the `commonName` when it's requested, as none of these belong in the CN per the RFC; instead, name the cert*
4. Cleanup:

   ```bsh
   rm -rf ~/ssltemp
   ```